# How to split values in Several rows (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, split, substring

I want split one row in several rows in SQL.

For example, I have **'A ADCT DROP INCALL -'** that contain **spaces** and a '-' and I want that there values remain separate in several rows for example.

**Original result:**

```
SELECT statuses FROM campaigns;
+-----------------------------------------+
| RESULT OF QUERY                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
| A ADCT DROP INCALL -                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

**The result must like:**

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| RESULT OF QUERY                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
| A                                       |
| ADCT                                    |
| DROP                                    |
| INCALL                                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I try with SUBSTRING_INDEX like:

```
SELECT status
FROM statuses
WHERE statuses.status NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(dial_statuses)," ", 1) FROM campaigns WHERE campaign_id = '4000')
ORDER BY STATUS;
```

I'm sorry, I know that is so basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) 
  name
FROM
  numbers 
INNER JOIN tablename ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
 -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfcc3/1).

If you cannot create a table, then a solution can be this:

```
SELECT
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) 
  name
FROM
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers 
INNER JOIN tablename ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
 -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n
```

an example fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a213e4/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try and create function in MySQL as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
   delim, '');
```

Then you should be able to use it like this in a query:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('a|bb|ccc|dd', '|', 3) as third;
```

This is untested but should work. For more info check [this](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) out.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading this correctly, then this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows):

[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

The answer states the following from @fthiella:

```
select
tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n
```

See a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffa86a/1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffa86a/1

Answer (score 0):

If you have to replace only spaces and - then you can use

SELECT  TRIM(BOTH "\n" FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name,' ', "\n"), "-", "\n")) FROM table;

you can skip trim from above statement if you want leading or trailing spaces from start and end.